# Access variable across methods Laravel PHP

Tags: php, laravel-5

Hey all actually I too facing the problem but I couldn't understand any of the above methods. Please help me to understand those stuffs and help t fix my problem.

I have two methods method1 and method2, where I receive some value in method 1 which needs to used in method 2. I created a variable on class level but I couldn't access the variable below is the code snippet.

```
class testController extends controller
{
    public $isChecked = false;
    public $isSelectedValue = 0;

    public function ValidateValue(Request $req)
    {
        $isChecked = $req->checked;
        $isSelectedValue = $req->value;
    }

    public function UsethoseValues()
    {
        if ($isChecked) { // I can't use the variable here it throws run time error. I need help on this please help.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to write `$this->isChecked` not `$isChecked`

Comment: Would probably help to read the [manual on class properties](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php).

Comment: @Joseph that solved my issue thanks

Comment: @GopiP accept the answer if it helped you, and thanks

Comment: @Jeto I recommend call class in CameCase it a good practice. There are
[PSR](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/#3-namespace-and-class-names)
describes those practices. It's fine when you work alone to not use any recommendation but when you going to work in a team member going to hate you.

Comment: @112Legion I think you meant to @ someone else. Also, that is called PascalCase :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you are in `class` and you declare a property not a simple variable
so when you try to access it from the method in your `class` you need to add `$this`

keyword that refer to your class

```
$this->isChecked
```

so your code will be like this after editing

```
class testController extends controller { 
        public $isChecked = false;
        public $isSelectedValue = 0;
public function ValidateValue(Request $req) {
        $this->isChecked = $req->checked;
        $this->isSelectedValue = $req->value;
     }
public function UsethoseValues() {
        if($this->isChecked) { // I can't use the variable here it throws run time error. I need help on this please help.
           }
     }
}
```

> feel free to check the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) for more info

Comment: thanks. I need another help. the value for $isChecked is reassigned in Validatevalue() method. which needs to be used in the usethoseValues() method. But, the value on $isChecked is not getting modified. Can you please help me on this?

Comment: @GopiP if you  answer a new question with your problem it would be more clear

Comment: done answer here kindly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59544402/reassign-with-new-value-to-global-variable-laravel-php