# Reassign with new value to global variable Laravel PHP

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a below kind of snippet in my Laravel project where I'm trying to re-assign value to the global variable `$ischecked` and `$isselectedValue` in a method `ValidateValue()` and I'm trying to access the same variable with the updated values in second method called `useThoseValues()` but I couldn't get the updated value. Kindly help me on this

```
class testController extends controller {

  public $isChecked = false;
  public $isSelectedValue = 0;

  public function ValidateValue(Request $req)
  {
    $isChecked = $req->checked;
    $isSelectedValue = $req->value;
  }

  public function UsethoseValues()
  {
    if ($this->isChecked) { // this variable values is not getting updated
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you want to affect an object property's value, `$this` is apparently necessary in PHP. See demo https://3v4l.org/kG3fZ The value still remains 0.

Comment: Would [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) help/clarify some things?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference/update `$isChecked` property using `$this` inside ValidateValue function. So your updated code should be:

```
public function ValidateValue(Request $req)
{
    $this->isChecked = $req->checked;
    $this->isSelectedValue = $req->value;
}
```